# Regex: How to specify captured group should contain a specfic word

Tags: php, regex

**Question :** How to match anchor tag which has ID attribute?

**My string**

```
<a href="something" id="someid" />
<a href="something" />
```

**Expected output:**

```
<a href="something" />
<a href="something" />
```

I need to delete `id` attribute in anchor tags.

I tried so far :

```
 <a(.*?)>  //how to specify `id` should be in the captured group
```

**Note**:  I have not used DOM parser for this, as it saves as HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check on this : https://regex101.com/r/cN9nR3/3

Expression : `<a[^>]*(id="[a-z]*").*>` should do it.

Comment: Yeah, and it will also delete `id` (and possibly some other attributes) of anything else, consider this input: `<a href="#foo"><img id="myimage" src="foobarbaz.png" /></a>`. Whoops, the `img` element suddenly lost its id and src attribute.

Comment: Yes! Sorry, no offense intended, I just wanted to get it right. Regular expressions can truly be a pain for HTML.

Comment: Np do'nt worry :D. Was just lazy to think about exceptions since he provided the string to work on. Anyway now the expression is a bit more sexy. Kappa.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following pattern :

```
$pattern=/^<a (href=".*?").*\/>$/mg
$replacement=<a $1 \/>
$st='<a href="something" id="someid" />\n<a href="something" />'
preg_replace ( $pattern ,$replacement , $st)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eD7fU4/1)